# Unable to create a directory using Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have tried something like this

```yaml
- name: Create a directory 
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: /etc/fail2ban
    state: directory
    mode: '0755'
```

and I am a getting a error

```json
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "There was an issue creating /etc/fail2ban as requested: [Errno 13] Permission denied: b'/etc/fail2ban'", "path": "/etc/fail2ban"}
```

I am trying to create a directory on a remote server.

Need Help !!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. Just an advice, avoid any operation with root user, create a dedicated user for defined task.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? -YLR

Comment: You say, "I am creating a directory on a remote server with root user", this point must be avoided. Nothing have to be do with root user.

Comment: Sorry my bad this is my first time here. The problem is I want to create a directory on remote server and when I tried it using Ansible I am getting a error permission denied. @YLR

Comment: Yes understand, it's just an advice around this subject, but it's out of scope of your question, that why it's just in a comment

Comment: According the message `[Errno 13] Permission denied` it seems to be because of insufficient rights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you already tested the execution with `become: yes`?

```yaml
- name: Create a directory 
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: /etc/fail2ban
    state: directory
    mode: '0755'
  become: yes
```

See the Ansible docs for more information on [become and privilege escalation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html).

Otherwise the output of `stat` might help you to understand what is going on. You could add the following two tasks before your `file` task:

```yaml
- name: Get file stat
  stat:
    path: /etc/fail2ban
  register: stat_result
- name: Print file stat
  debug:
    var: stat_result
```

Comment: Either add `become: yes` to your playbook or use the `-b/--become` option of `ansible-playbook`.